# Continuously Extending Arithmetic

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, binary-operations

Let $\mathbb R^+$ be the set of positive real numbers and let the natural numbers be $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1,2,3,\ldots \}$. Let $\star_x$ be an operator on $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that

\begin{align}
a \star_0 b &= a + b \\
a \star_1 b &= a \cdot b \\
a \star_2 b &= a^b
\end{align}

And so on. In particular, if $b\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\star_x$ satisfies the recursive property

$$
y \star_x b = \underbrace{y \star_{x-1} y \star_{x-1} \cdots \star_{x-1} y}_{b \text{ times}}
$$

Is there a natural way of extending $\star_x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ so that the map $(a,b) \mapsto a \star_x b$ is a continuous function of $x$? (EDIT: And, hopefully, a continuous function of $a$ and $b$?)

Comment: What would it be for $x=1/2$ [midway between sum and product]?

Comment: Um.... $a \star_x b = a\star_{\lfloor x \rfloor}b + (a\star_{\lceil x \rceil}b - a\star_{\lfloor x \rfloor}b)*(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$?  i.e. just connect $a \star_x b$ to $a\star_{x+1} b$ with a straight line.  You don't have any other condition to be satisfied.

Comment: @fleablood That certainly works, and is arguably "natural". I was hoping for something more elegant (in the sense that it might satisfy some nice recursive properties), but that definitely works. Thanks!

Comment: But it's not differentiable or smooth which would be tighter conditions.  And that would make for a very difficult problem which.... I'll let someone else contemplate.